# Can each subscriber get different values from one Flowable?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

When some subscribers subscribe one flowable and this flowable emit items to subscribers, can each subscriber get a different value?

For example, if a flowable emits

0, 1, 2, 3...

one observer gets 0, 2 and the other observer get 1, 3, and so on, like a load balancer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ParallelFlowable is something closer to what I wanted to do.
It's available since 2.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

How about this solution ?

```
  @Test
  public void testFlowableLoadBalancer() {
    IntStream stream = IntStream.iterate(1, i -> i + 1);
    Flowable<Integer> flowable = Flowable.create(e -> stream.forEach(i -> {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
      }
      e.onNext(i);
    }), BackpressureStrategy.DROP);


    ConnectableFlowable<Integer> cf = flowable.publish();

    cf.filter(i -> i % 2 == 0).subscribe(i -> {
      logger.info("[even] i = {}" , i);
    });

    cf.filter(i -> i % 2 == 1).subscribe(i -> {
      logger.info("[ odd] i = {}" , i);
    });

    cf.connect();
  }
```

The output :

```
2016-11-11 18:15:57,884 INFO  data.Rx2Test - [ odd] i = 1
2016-11-11 18:15:58,892 INFO  data.Rx2Test - [even] i = 2
2016-11-11 18:15:59,895 INFO  data.Rx2Test - [ odd] i = 3
2016-11-11 18:16:00,900 INFO  data.Rx2Test - [even] i = 4
```

Problem unsolved : this cannot auto balance , pending for other answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My purpose is that, when one subscriber got a trouble with consuming, the other subscriber got items automatically. For example, when I want to send data from observer to servers over the network and one server got down, the other observer can send the data to the other server instead.  I just wonder whether there were the solution already. I'm not hurry. So, when I found the solution, I 'll share it.